# Reading FFmpeg bytes from named pipes, extracted NAL units are bad/corrupted

Tags: .net, ffmpeg, webrtc, h.264, named-pipes

I'm trying to read .mp4 file wtih ffmpeg and read bytes from the named pipe which I then want to package to RTP stream and send those packets over WebRTC.

What I learned is that H264 video consists of many NAL units. So What I do in my code is read the bytes from the named pipe and try to extract NAL units. The problem is that the bytes I get seem to make no real sense as NAL unit start is sometimes only few bytes away.

I tested on multiple different mp4 files and on multiple h264 files, all have the same issues. Start of NAL units are found but they aren't separated properly, or what I'm reading aren't NAL units at all. For example NAL units start from reading a sample .h264 file would be: 4, 32, 41, 717. This does not make a lot of sense if these are NAL units, they are too close and some are far apart. I'm lost at what I'm doing wrong.

The issue might also be in the ffmpeg command itself. I do think I need "-c:v libx264 -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb" arguments for the output to be in the correct format but I'm not certain.

I did try sending NAL units that seemed ok over webrtc but nothing was displayed on the receiving end (probably because of how H264 works by needing previous frames, I'm not sure).

I am struggling with this issue for past few days now and no matter what I tried NAL units were never as they should be.

Code to start ffmpeg process from c#:

```cs
var proc = new Process()
{
    StartInfo =
        {
            FileName = FFMPEG_LIB_PATH,
            Arguments = "-y -re -i input.mp4 -an -c:v libx264 -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f image2pipe ffmpeg_rec_stream",
            UseShellExecute = false,
            CreateNoWindow = true,
            RedirectStandardInput = false,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        }
};
```

Code to connect to named pipe:

```cs
var mOutputPipe = new NamedPipeServerStream($"ffmpeg_rec_stream", PipeDirection.InOut, 1, PipeTransmissionMode.Byte, PipeOptions.Asynchronous, 102400, 102400);
mOutputPipe.BeginWaitForConnection(OnOutputPipeConnected, null);
```

Code for OnOutputPipeConnected

```cs
private void OnOutputPipeConnected(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            try
            {
                mOutputPipe.EndWaitForConnection(ar);
                var buffer = new byte[65536];
                while (true)
                {
                    int bytesRead = mOutputPipe.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    if (bytesRead == 0)
                    {
                        break;
                    }

                    var nalUnitStarts = FindAllNalUnitIndexes(buffer, bytesRead);
                    for (int i = 0; i < nalUnitStarts.Count - 1; i++)
                    {
                        int nalStartIndex = nalUnitStarts[i];
                        int nalEndIndex = nalUnitStarts[i + 1] - 1;
                        int nalLength = nalEndIndex - nalStartIndex + 1;
                        byte[] nalUnit = new byte[nalLength];
                        Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer, nalStartIndex, nalUnit, 0, nalLength);

                        // send nalUnit over to webrtc client
                        var rtpPacket = new RTPPacket(nalUnit);
                        RecordingSession?.RTCPeer.SendRtpRaw(SDPMediaTypesEnum.video, rtpPacket.Payload, rtpPacket.Header.Timestamp, rtpPacket.Header.MarkerBit, 100);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                
            }
        }
```

Code for finding NAL units:

```cs
private static List<int> FindAllNalUnitIndexes(byte[] buffer, int length)
{
    var indexes = new List<int>();
    int i = 0;

    while (i < length - 4)
    {
        int nalStart = FindNextNalUnit(buffer, i, length);
        if (nalStart == -1)
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            indexes.Add(nalStart);
            i = nalStart + 1;
        }
    }

    return indexes;
}

private static int FindNextNalUnit(byte[] buffer, int startIndex, int length)
{
    for (int i = startIndex; i < length - 4; i++)
    {
        if (buffer[i] == 0 && buffer[i + 1] == 0 && (buffer[i + 2] == 1 || (buffer[i + 2] == 0 && buffer[i + 3] == 1)))
        {
            return i + (buffer[i + 2] == 1 ? 3 : 4);
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Replace `-bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f image2pipe` with `-f h264`. WebRTC doesn't support B-Frames. Add `-bf 0` for disabling B-Frames. Beside that, parsing the NAL units "manually" is challenging - consider the fact that an encoded video packet may include more then one NAL unit.

Comment: I believe you can find many answers in https://github.com/mpromonet/webrtc-streamer. Maybe this project can satisfy you requirements as is.

Comment: @Rotem I tried what you said, so my command now looks like: "ffmpeg -y -re -i {@"C:\Users\User\Downloads\video.mp4"} -c:v libx264 -an -bf 0 -f h264 {outputPipeName}" but unfortunately FindAllNalUnitIndexes function still returns NAL unit index that make no sense (32768 bytes read, nal units start at indexes 4, 35, 44, 659)

Comment: Considering the fact that an encoded video packet may include more then one NAL unit, like SPS and PPS... Short NAL units does make sense.